# I am not able to understand what is exactly happening in this code. What does the last arguement of subset function is doing?

Tags: r, data.table

```
x <-2
    df_new <-
      subset(
        df,
        select = c(
          AccountType,
          Theme,
          Segment,
          Country,
          DrillDown,
          ID,
          CurrentAmount,
          ComparisonAmount,
          VarianceAmount,
          VariancePercent
        ) ,
        AccountType == paste0(df_old$AccountType[[x]])
      )
```

I am not able to understand what does the last part of the Subset function is doing? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: It is checking whether the 'AccountType' elements arer the same as the character convertedd column of 'df_old' 'AccountType' and doing a filtering of the rows (assuming that both 'df' and 'df_old' have the same number of rows.  Basically, it is doing an elementwise comparison

Comment: Anyone have any idea why someone would want to coerce `df_old$AccountType[[x]]` with `paste0` as opposed to `as.character()` other than the obvious that it's shorter?

Comment: So, does that mean 'df_new' will have all the selected columns (and rows) same as 'df' except for the column 'AccountType' where the values that are common to 'df' and 'df_old' will only be considered? @akrun

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is checking whether the 'AccountType' elements in 'df' are the same as the character converted column of 'df_old' 'AccountType' (`paste0`) and doing a conversion to `character`  for the second element (`x <- 2`) and based on that filtering of the rows are  carried out.

It is unclear whether `paste0` is used in a different purpose or not because it  would make sense to use `paste0` when there are multiple arguments

```
paste0('s', 42)
[1] "s42"
```

Based on the code, if we do it on a single element,

```
paste0(42)# converts to character class  which can be done with `as.character`
#[1] "42"
```

---

Here, the `==` is to subset the rows, and `select` is for selecting the columns.   Using a reproducible example

```
subset(head(mtcars),  select = c(mpg, cyl),  subset = cyl == 6)
#                mpg cyl
#Mazda RX4      21.0   6
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6
#Valiant        18.1   6
```

Comment: Great! Very well explained! So, what I understood is that here, the first argument of the subset function will choose the rows from df, the second argument will choose the columns that satisfy the third argument with the condition on which the filtering is done?

Comment: @abhi_47  It is the `select` arrgument - column, `subset` for filtering rows.  You can specify the argument in any orderr as long as you specify the argument alsso.  otherwise, have to follow the order of arguments in the function doc